# Macbook won't connect to EAP-TTLS network

Tags: wifi, apple-silicon

My m1 pro 2021 model MacBook Pro will not connect to my university's secure wifi network. It uses 802.1x and EAP-TTLS to connect but when I enter my username and password it tries to connect but says "self-assigned ip".

Comment: This is likely something you need to contact you uni’s IT support for. The IP address is self assigned because you didn’t get an IP address from the DHCP server because you didn’t authenticate properly.